# Print latex code to .tex file using cat() or print()

Tags: r, printing, latex, cat, sink

I want to print a chunk of latex code using R. I've previously used cat() to do this, my problem is that it quickly becomes a cumbersome task when I have a large body of text including tables written in latex as I have to include additional backslashes in R. i.e., if I want a tex-file with the following:

```
\begin{document}
```

I would need to write something like

`cat("\\begin{document}", file= test.tex, append = T, sep="\n")`

in R.

I've also tried:

```
sink("test.tex")
print("\begin{document}", quote = F)
sink()
```

which almost gives me the desired result except for the fact that it prints row numbers in front of the text, more specifically it prints:

```
[1] \begin{document}
```

Is there a way to write plain latex code in R and get it to work properly without adding additional backslashes or row numbers?
I know there are more sophisticated solutions using sweave, knitr, Rmarkdown but would prefer to a solution using print/writeLines/cat, etc.

Comment: If you get `[1] \begin{document}` with an editor supporting replacement of regular expressions, like RStudio, it is quite easy to remove all substrings as `[1] `

Answer (score 1):

If you are pasting text into the console or piping a file into R from the command line, you can use something like this:

```
latex <- scan(what = character())
\begin{document}
\end{document}

writeLines(latex, "test.tex")
```

where the blank line tells `scan()` to stop reading.  However, if you put those lines in a file and `source()` it, you'll get an error, because it's not all syntactically correct R code.

You're definitely better off to use `knitr` with `.Rnw` input.